# Universal quantifier question: $(\forall x)[x < 0 \Rightarrow x^2 > 0]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Universal quantifier question: $(\forall x)[x < 0 \Rightarrow  x^2 > 0]$. 
Given the above expression, For all of $x$ [ if $x$ is less than zero, then $x^2$ is greater than zero].

Is that a true statement?

The confusion: $p \Rightarrow q$, is true in all cases except when $p$ is true and $q$ is false. In the above problem, if $x < 0$  is true then $x^2 > 0$ will be true. But, when, $x = 0$, then, the premise $x < 0$ is false. But, according to definition, if premise is false, the expression is still considered true. Doesn't it contradict?

Comment: Doesn't *what* contradict? Your reasoning is correct - in the case $x=0$ the premise $x<0$ is false, hence the statement $x<0\rightarrow x^2>0$ is (vacuously) true.

Comment: It seems I was confused with the conclusion being true/false and the true/false of the overall expression. I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The confusion: p → q, is true in all cases except when p is true and q is false. In the above problem, if x < 0 is true then x² > 0 will be true. But, when, x = 0, then, the premise x < 0 is false. But, according to definition, if premise is false, the expression is still considered true. Doesn't it contradict?

Where the *antecedent* of an implication is false, it is the **statement** that is held to be true; not necessarily its *consequent*.

That is, an implication statement is true if: *either* the antecedent and the consequent are *both* true, *or* the antecedent is false (whatever the consequent may be).   Which is the same as saying that an implication statement is considered false *only if*: the antecedent is true while the consequent is false.

Hence, the statement $\forall x \;(x<0 \,\to\, x^2> 0)$ will be contradicted only by an example, $c$, such that $c<0$ *and* $c^2\leq 0$.   The example of $0$ does not contradict the statement.

---

- "All ducks fly south for the winter" is not contradicted by non-migrating emus.

$$\forall \text{bird}\;(\text{bird}\in\text{Ducks}\;\to\;\text{bird}\in\text{Southward winter migrators}) \\ \text{Emu}\not\in\text{Ducks}\;\wedge\;\text{Emu}\not\in\text{Southward winter migrators} \\ \ldots$$

- "All swans are white" was contradicted by finding black swans.

$$\forall \text{bird}\;(\text{bird}\in\text{Swans}\;\to\;\text{bird}\in\text{White feathered}) \\\text{Black Swan}\in\text{Swans}\;\wedge\;\text{Black Swan}\not\in\text{White feathered}\\\text{Contradiction!}$$